# Exercise in computing $P(X>0,Y>0)$ given a distribution density function for $(X,Y)$

Tags: probability, self-study

> **Exercise:** Given $p \in (0,1)$ and $(X,Y)$ a pair of RV with distribution density function $$f(x,y)= \frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{1-p^2}}\exp \left( -\frac{1}{2(1-p^2)}(x^2-2pxy+y^2) \right) $$
>   Compute $P(X>0,Y>0)$

---

**My approach**: The calculation as it is stated above might be very hard, however since this a guided (not mandatory) exercise I first had to show that in fact $X$ and $Z=(Y-pX)/\sqrt{1-p^2}$ are two **independent** standard Gaussian RV, which I managed to complete.

My idea was now to use this knowledge and apply it to the above problem. Evidently we have: $$Y >0 \iff Z=\frac{Y-pX}{\sqrt{1-p^2}}> \frac{-pX}{\sqrt{1-p^2}}=:z_X $$
Therefore I obtain $$P(X>0,Y>0)=P(X>0,Z>z_X)=P(X>0)P(Z>z_X) =\frac{1}{2}P(Z>z_X) $$ using the independence of $X,Z$ and that $X$ has standard Gauss distribution. If these steps so far are correct then I am stuck on how to compute $$P(Z>z_X)= P \left( Z> -pX/\sqrt{1-p^2}\right) $$
The resulting integral still seems very complicated to me and I am not sure if there exists a closed form of it, according to some experiments I have done with WolframAlpha it does.

According to WolframAlpha for $p=0.5$ we get  $P(X>0,Y>0)=0.33333 $ however this might be a numerical approximation.

**Update:** As mentioned by Professor @Xi'an since $z_X$ depends on $X$ I cannot use the 'independence' of $X,Z$ in order to write the probabilities as a product. However  $$P(X>0,Y>0)=P\left(X>0,Z> -pX/\sqrt{1-p^2}\right) $$ still gives the correct bounds for the integral. The next promising step might be to change into polar coordinates

Comment: You cannot break your probability into a product since $z_X$ depends on $X$.

Comment: There is a nice derivation of this (the bivariate Normal orthant prob) at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1687795/correlated-joint-normal-distribution-calculating-a-probability

Comment: Thanks a lot @Xi'an, this makes sense to me. Unfortunately  this only means that I am more lost now on this exercise. My intuition was to make use of the RV $Z$ but this might be all for nothing now ;)

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot @wolfies, I suppose I greatly underestimated this problem then, the solution provided there seems to be a nice approach but way out of reach for me to fully grasp yet. on the math.SE link you provided I also found this http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/64068-Analytic-form-for-the-quadrant-probability-of-a-(standard)-bivariate-t-distribution?p=185687&viewfull=1#post185687 which seems to be helpful.

Comment: There is also a derivation in: Stigler (1989), Normal outhant probabilities, _American Statistician_, 43, p.291 ..., as well as Stuart and Ord, Kendal's Advanced Theory of Stats

Comment: Perhaps a swtich to polar coordinates, after switching to independent rvs x and z?  That still really just leaves the geometry though, as you need to correctly adjust the ranges of integration into polar coordinates.

Comment: Thanks @probabilityislogic, this is a great piece of advice! I am working on it at the moment. In case I will manage to do so I will try to write an answer here.

Comment: Invariance by rotation of 2D standard normal distribution yields $$\frac14+\frac1{2\pi}\arcsin p.$$